# phonegap app disable button after click

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, button, phonegap-build

I am building an app for iOS using phonegap. I have a button on the screen that I want it to be disabled after the user clicked it once. I've researched the web on how to do it but the javascript code I found doesn't appear to be working in phonegap for some reason.

Here's my button:

```
<input id="takenbutton"  class="round-button" type="button" value="Taken" name="run_button"  onClick="taken()">
```

The taken() function will be coded so that it logs the date and time the user clicked the button, so that function is needed.

Comment: what about `taken(this)`? Then you can use `this.disabled = true` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**in your script.**

```
$('#takenbutton').click(function(){
     $('input[type="button"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: In latest cordova default template, you can allow inline javascript configuring the content security policy meta tag